# When media recorder start recording video then "onPreviewFrame" method of Camera.PreviewCallback stopped working

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, miui

I am writing code to record video after analyzing frame. If the frame contains a redness level above 240 then it starts recording or redness goes bellow 230 stop video recording.

But the issue is that when media recorder starts recording than the **onPreviewFrame** method of **Camera.PreviewCallback** stopped working for customized android OS MIUI of my android device **Redmi note 7 pro**.

My code is bellow

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

       /**
        * {@inheritDoc}
        */
       @Override
       public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
           if (data == null) throw new NullPointerException();
           Camera.Size size = cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
           if (size == null) throw new NullPointerException();


           int width = size.width;
           int height = size.height;

           // decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg function to find redness lavel of frame 
           int imgAvg = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg(data.clone(), height, width);
           Log.i(TAG, "imgAvg=" + imgAvg);
           if (imgAvg == 0 || imgAvg == 255) {
               return;
           }

           if (isRecording) {
               long diffInMs = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime() - startTime;
               Log.i(TAG, imgAvg + " imgAvg diffInMs1=" + diffInMs);

               mProgressBar.setProgress((int) diffInMs);
               if (diffInMs >= recordingMS + 1000) {
                   stopRecording();
                   i = 0;
                   mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   tvStatingCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
               tvStatingCount.setText(getString(R.string.reading_started_please_hold_your_finger_steady_for_one_minute) + imgAvg);
           } else {
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               tvStatingCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               tvStatingCount.setText(getString(R.string.please_place_your_finger_over_your_rear_camera_to_start_the_readingt) + imgAvg);
           }

           if (imgAvg > 240) {
               if (!isRecording) {
                   starRecording();
                   i = 0;
                   mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                   mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   tvStatingCount.setText(getString(R.string.reading_started_please_hold_your_finger_steady_for_one_minute) + imgAvg);
               }
           } else {
               if (isRecording && imgAvg < 230) {
                   stopRecording();
               }
               /*mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               tvStatingCount.setText(getString(R.string.please_place_your_finger_over_your_rear_camera_to_start_the_readingt, imgAvg));*/
           }
       }
   };
```

The code is working for the native Android version. tested code in device moto, Samsung.

so anyone can help me to find out the solution?